# Vb.net packaging & distribution of resources such as images

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce

Since form objects and forms themselves have images (window icons, img on buttons, etc.) that are in a specific folder (img) under the project root, I wanted to figure out **how to include the folder with all its contents within the publish profile** which uses ClickOnce to generate the "install kit"?

I searched and searched but found nothing.

Comment: If you add those resource to the project, there is an option to set the build action to copy to output folder, which will then used by clickonce automatically

Answer (score 0):

Select the item(s) in the *Solution Explorer* and open the *Properties* window. You should set the `Build Action` property to `Content` and then set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` or, preferably, `Copy if newer`. The folder and its contents will be copied to the output folder, along with your EXE, and included in the publish automatically, although you might want to check that on the *Publish* page of the project properties. You should use `Application.StartupPath` as the folder path root in code to access the files.

Answer (score 0):

In the publish settings, click on the **Application Files**, and **Include** the respective file. If you do not see the file, check the **Show All Files**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Copy to Output Directory property of each image in the folder to Copy always or Copy if newer, and then follow these steps:

1. Right-click the project and select Properties in Solution Explorer.
2. In the project properties, switch to the Publishing tab.
3. Click the Application File button to open a dialog box.
4. In the dialog, locate the "img" folder in the file list and change
   its "Publish Status" to "Include".
5. Make sure the "Publish Status" of the image files in the "img"
   folder is also set to "Include".